# CreateWindow() in headless app

Tags: c++, sockets, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

I've created a headless app (Win32 project actually) targeting ARM - RaspberryPi2 with Windows 10 IoT on it. I need to create Async socket and a helper window for messages. But unfortunately CreateWindow() fails and GetLastError returns zero - that's probably caused because there are no active screens on RPi. Is there any workaround?

Comment: lol, Windows, API fails and GLE returns success.  I'm glad it's you and not me:)

Comment: This is a very standard programming bug in the window procedure.  This is not youtube, we can't see it from here.